# AV in dll, only on client machine - how to debug?

Tags: windows, debugging, dll, access-violation

I get an Access violation in one of my dll's, only on the client machine where I don't have access. All I have is the error message "Access violation at adress ABCDEF in module ghij.dll. Reading address 0x0000123". Can I use this information to pinpoint in which function the AV happened? Is this some static address inside the DLL? Or does it at least stay the same when running on a different machine, and one can somehow dump the functions at runtime?

Comment: Can't you enable minidump file creation on the client machine?

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks, creating a dump is a good idea.